# How to find a function with given requirements?

Tags: calculus, functions

I am trying to come up with a function $f(x): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies following requirements:

1. $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable
2. $f(x) \ge 0$ for every $x$
3. $f(x) = h \cdot b^x$ for every integer $x$ ($h, b \in \mathbb{R}, h \gt 0, 0 \lt b \lt 1$)
4. $f'(x) = 0$ for every integer $x$
5. $f(x) = 0$ for every $x \in \{0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, ...\}$

I came up with $ f(x) = h \cdot b^x \cdot \frac{\cos{2\pi x} + 1}{2} $ by intuition. Even though it satisfies requirements 1, 2, 3 and 5, it fails at the requirement 4.

So what would be a correct approach to this problem? Also, what would be a correct approach to problems of this type in general? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your guess a bit to obtain a function satisfying the properties:

$$ f(x) = hb^{\lfloor x+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor} \cos^2(\pi x). $$

The discontinuities of $hb^{\lfloor x+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor}$ at half-integers do not matter, because the derivative of $\cos^2(\pi x)$ vanishes at those points. Below is the picture of the graph of $f$ and $f'$ when $h = 1$ and $b = 1/2$.

[image: Graph of f(x) and f'(x)]

Comment: That is an interesting solution and it perfectly suits the purpose. Thank you!